# How to redirect all my urls with no extension to end with .php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I originally wanted to have all my urls end with no extension. Unfortunately, I've tried many htaccess codes and I've just about given up.

So now I want to make it so if a person wants to visit a page in my site, but forgets to enter .php, he/she will automatically be redirected to the same url but with the .php

How can this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here are the rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

1. It will check if requested resource is not a existing folder. For example: you requesting `http://www.example.com/help`. If there is such folder present (`/help`) the rule will do nothing (priority is given to a folder). **If** you do not want this behaviour then remove the first line.
2. It will check if there is such .php file before rewriting. For example: you requesting `http://www.example.com/aboutus` but there is NO `aboutus.php` file there -- no rewrite will occur.
3. All such requests should be without trailing slash: should be `http://www.example.com/aboutus` and NOT `http://www.example.com/aboutus/`
4. The rule will work for URL in subfolders as well: e.g. `http://www.example.com/pages/help/aboutus` will be rewritten just fine.
5. Because of the above checks the rule will not enter into a rewrite loop (no 500 error on this rule)
6. Query string (page parameters) will be preserved

Answer (score 4):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: I want to extend this rule by redirect index.php or index url request to base url.

Comment: this rewrite rule is not working for post requests.

Answer (score 1):

In response to Sun Love, the code you posted works well except for situations where you have a trailing slash without the file extension (I get a 500 error) because the first RegEx doesn't match for this situation.

> example.com/test.html -- works (redirects to /test)
>
> example.com/test -- works (no redirect)
>
> example.com/test.html -- works (redirects to /test)
>
> example.com/test/ -- doesn't work (500 error)

There is probably a better way to do this but I added another rewrite condition to fix this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+).php
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)/\s
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

EDIT: `^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]`

Comment: I already started my htaccess code with
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

will it affect my other htaccess codes if I add the Options+FollowSymLinks at the beginning? If yes, what should i do?

Comment: I don't think that it will affect your current .htaccess.

It specifies whether or not apache should follow a symbolic link while looking for a file.
For example, if you have a file
`/home/mydomain/www/myfile.html`
which is a link to
`/home/mydomain/somedir/therealfile.html`

Then apache will only retrieve the realfile.html if you have that option enabled. Just try. More info at [http://www.maxi-pedia.com/FollowSymLinks](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/FollowSymLinks)

Comment: Well I just tried RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L] without the Options and I got a 500 error. I added the Options +FollowSymLinks and I still got a 500 error. Hmm, :-/

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]`. I am almost 99% sure that it will work.